# Move Jenkins config from one Kubernetes cluster to another

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have inherited a Jenkins installation which is used by multiple remote teams, and running on an Amazon EKS cluster. For reasons that are not really relevant, I need to move this Jenkins workload to a new EKS cluster.

Deploying jenkins itself is not a major issue, I am doing so using helm. The persistence of the existing jenkins deployment is bound to an Amazon EBS volume, the persistence of the new deployment will also be. The mount point will be `/var/jenkins_home`

I'm trying to find a simple way of migrating everything from the current jenkins installation and configuration to the new one. This includes mainly:

Authorization Strategy (RBAC)
Jobs
Plugins
Cloud and Agent Config

I know that everything required is most likely in Jenkins Home. Could I in theory just dump out the current Jenkins Home folder and import into the new running jenkins container using `kubetl cp` or something like that? Is there an easier way? Is this unsafe in some way?

Comment: if you're doing backups (which I hope you do) of your jenkins home directory, you could have created one explicitly, stop the old instance, recover from backup on the other cluster and start it. If you're not doing backups - please do.

Comment: @zerkms There are no backups of Jenkins Home, other than snapshots of the EBS volume. I am guessing that the backup/restore process for this will be to backup jenkins_home folder, maybe to S3 for example (I did this today), and restore would be to copy that to the jenkins_home folder of destination server overwriting jenkins_home, and restart container/service?

Backing up jenkins_home will be implemented when moved to more stable EKS build. I'll make sure of that.